# How to setup console application with autowire commands?

Tags: symfony

Please help me with config Console App, in first - config

```
 #!/usr/bin/env php
 <?php
 use  ....
 ...
 $container = new ContainerBuilder();
 $config = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__));
 $config->load('config.yml');
 $output = $container->get('symfony.console_output');$logger = $container->get('logger');
 //I want automatic injection!!!!
 $helloCommand = new HelloCommand($container, $logger);
 $application = $container->get('symfony.application');
 $application->add($helloCommand);
 $application->run(null, $output);
```

And my config.yml

```
services:
logger:
    class: Symfony\Component\Console\Logger\ConsoleLogger
    arguments:
        - '@symfony.console_output'
symfony.application:
    class: Symfony\Component\Console\Application
    calls:
        //by this variant autowire not working
        - [add, [ '@app.command.hello_command' ]]
        - [setDispatcher, ['@symfony.event_dispatcher']]
...
app.command.hello_command:
    class: App\Command\HelloCommand
    autowire:   true
    tags:
        -  { name: console.command }
```

So my HelloCommand has constructor with ContainerInterface and LoggerInterface and it work only if i set this arguments directly, other i have error about wrong constructor

Or may be exists another way for configuration with config.yml 
for only logger - its will be simple  by set ['@logger'] as arguments, but how can i set current container as argument? 
Or i`ll have to install full symfony with httpkernel (but it does not need)

HelloCommand
http://pastebin.com/VRr3FM7Q

***THE DECISION***

```
        app.command.hello_command:
        class: App\Command\HelloCommand
        arguments:
                - '@service_container'
                - '@logger'
        tags:
            -  { name: console.command }
```

Comment: Why do you manually create an object of the `HelloCommand` if you already try to register it as a service? Please also show the code of your `HelloCommand` class.

Comment: it alternative variant; for illustration, that if i create if manual with initinalization - all ok, but with config injection not works

Comment: HelloCommand http://pastebin.com/VRr3FM7Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in how you configure your command:

```
app.command.hello_command:
    class: App\Command\HelloCommand
    autowire: true
    tags:
        -  { name: console.command }
```

This misses the 2 constructor arguments required: `$container`, `$logger` and is probably why you get the exception. You can add constructor arguments like this:

```
app.command.hello_command:
    class: App\Command\HelloCommand
    arguments:
        - '@service_container'
        - '@logger'
    [...]
```

I'm not sure if the id for the service_container is right. I never pass the container or make things ContainerAware, but you get the general idea. ;)

Comment: It goes without saying. The problem lies in the fact that i dont know how to specify container id

Comment: But '@service_container' - it`s correct!!!  All works without manual definition in app.php a lot of thanks!

Comment: I would have expected autowire to remove the need to explicitly define the arguments section in your services file.  Did you correctly type hint the arguments in your command constructor?